# Regex to match: Every word must have NO capitalized letters after first letter. First letter can be capitalized OR not capitalized

Tags: java, regex

**Dear regex experts**,

This is the rule I try to achieve, and I fail miserably I admit.

The **rule in words**:

- "**Every word** of a String **MUST have NO capitalized letters after first letter**. The **first letter may be** capitalized OR **may** also **not be** capitalized."

I try to add examples.

**Examples matching** the **whole String**:

- "Jean Luke Smith"
- "Jean Smith"
- "Jean"
- "jean luke smith"
- "jean smith"
- "jean"
- "Jean luke smith"
- "jean Luke smith"
- "jean luke Smith"

**Examples NOT matching** the **whole String** (I make bold what should be the not matching factor of the whole String):

- "J**E**an luk**K**e smi**TH**"
- "J**EAN** S**M**ith"
- "j**EA**n"
- "je**A**n luke smith"
- "Jea**N** sm**I**th"
- "j**EA**n"
- "Jean luke s**M**ith"
- "jean Lu**K**e smith"

I have tried several approaches, but all lead to non usable result.
I doubt that my tries are of any help, but I still add them here (I admit its more guessing than understanding...):

```
\b[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*
\b[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*\b
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]*\b
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*
```

Comment: if only ASCII is accepted `\b[A-Za-z][a-z]*\b` ? (`(?U)\b\p{Alpha}\p{Lower}*\b` for Unicode alphabetic characters like in "März")

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I get a:
`( Incomplete group structure
\p{Alpha} This script is unknown/invalid
\p{Lower} This script is unknown/invalid
* The preceding token is not quantifiable( Incomplete group structure
\p{Alpha} This script is unknown/invalid
\p{Lower} This script is unknown/invalid
* The preceding token is not quantifiable`

Comment: Are you really using Java? The proposed patterns are Java-regex compliant. I think you are looking for something like `^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*` (or `(?U)^(?!.*\b\p{Alpha}+\p{Upper}).*`)

Comment: works for me: https://ideone.com/SgIbPp (using Java since the question is tagged with [tag:java])

Comment: @ Wiktor:
I tried to test first on a page like 'regex101.com/' as its easier to test as runtime in Java. You're right, in Java it allows this kind of expression.

I tested all three expressions now in Java:
`\b[A-Za-z][a-z]*\b ? ((?U)\b\p{Alpha}\p{Lower}*\b)`
`^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*`
`(?U)^(?!.*\b\p{Alpha}+\p{Upper}).*`
Result (always false):
- "teSt" -> false
- "test" -> false

Comment: BTW this is a Question&Answer site, **NOT** a usual forum, please stop adding NOISE like "Dear regex experts" -- not needed since the question is already marked with the [tag:regex] ! I will not remove it again :-/    BTW2 using too much emphasis makes the question more difficult to read and no real advantage to emphasize everything (if everything is more important than the *rest*, there is no *rest*).

Comment: @user85421 ok sorry. Just wanted to be polight. Got it.

Comment: check [Should I remove 'fluff' (like greetings, signatures, "thanks", etc.) when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/85421) **and** [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) from the [help] || BTW3 regex101.com *must* be set to the Java language (and even then it i not 100% conform)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:

**Correction from the above**, was my error.

I tested your expressions now correctly, this one seems **to work fine**:
`^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*`

Comment: The suggestions from user85421 work fine in regex101.com too, you just have to care to select Java in “Flavor” list…

Comment: Maybe something like [`^\P{L}*(?:\p{L}\p{Ll}*\b\P{L}*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1MibEC/1)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a pattern that will match any string but a string containing a word that has an uppercase letter anywhere after the first letter.

The pattern would be

```
^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*
```

If you need to make it more Unicode-aware, use

```
(?U)^(?!.*\b\p{L}+\p{Lu}).*
```

And if you need to match a string with linebreaks:

```
(?Us)^(?!.*\b\p{L}+\p{Lu}).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDdiAE/1).

*Details*:

- `(?Us)` - `U` allows any escape sequences be Unicode-aware and `s` allows a `.` to match any chars including line break chars
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b\p{L}+\p{Lu})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars as many as possible  and then a word that has one or more letters at the start and then there is an uppercase letter
- `.*` - any zero or more chars (if `s` is not used - excluding line break chars) as many as possible.

Do not forget to double escape backslashes in the regex pattern when you put it into a string literal in the Java code (e.g. `String regex = "(?Us)^(?!.*\\b\\p{L}+\\p{Lu}).*";`).

Comment: Good answer, can I suggest .* at the end changed to .+ as not to match empty lines.

Comment: @Ishan I am not sure only non-empty strings must be matched here. Let OP decide if it is required or not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.
This one works well:
`^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*`

Answer (score 1):

Your patterns won't work because after the word boundary they should validate that after the first character there is no uppercase A-Z and match at least one character.

The patterns match:

```
\b[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*               // Optional char A-Z and optional chars [a-z]
\b[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*\b.            // The same but followed by a word boundary
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]*\b  // Asserts that there is not a single char A-Z
\b(?![A-Z]+\b)[A-Z]{0,1}[a-z]*   // The same with different character classes
```

If there are no other constraints, you might also turn the logic around and consider it a valid string if there is no match.

You can make use of the word boundary, and then make sure that the A-Z comes after the first character.

```
String[] strings = {"Jean Luke Smith", "JEan lukKe smiTH"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]");

for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if(!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    } 
}
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/55zeDo).

Output

```
Jean Luke Smith
```

Or if you want to allow more characters, you can make use of a whitespace boundary to the left:

```
(?<!\S)\S+?[A-Z]
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UicTYm/1) for the matches.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.
This one works well:
`^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*`

Answer (score 0):

For my case this one works well:

`^(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Z]).*`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).